# Where to pay taxes if working remotely and freelancing

Tags: united-kingdom, tax-law, european-union

I am a student, and I am thinking to start working (freelancing) on an online platform where I will deliver online courses that people will pay to have access.

The platform, as far as I am aware does not pay the taxes on my income, but they do get a small portion from my sales.

As a student I spent most of the time of the year in the UK. However, several months of the year I am spending them in my home country which is in the European Union.

If I will produce content (video creation etc) in both countries (some times in the UK and some times in my home country) in which country should I pay my taxes? So based on my income and the expenses I will have from this freelancing, I would like to pay my taxes in my home country, since in 5-10 years I will probably return permanently in my home country.

Is it legal to have my income going to a bank in my home country and therefore pay taxes to my home country's government if some if not most of the content I will produce will be in the UK?

Note that I will not own a company for this freelancing at all, it will be just a person producing online courses in an online platform.

Thanks

Comment: Why does the fact you will return home, mean you want to pay taxes in your home country?

Comment: I would phone up the Inland Revenue, and ask them.  They *are* actually helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's all according to the laws of both countries in question.
Most of the cases you should pay your taxes where is your tax residency. Your tax residency by default is where you spend more than half of a calendar year.
The only exception would be if you were simultaneously a resident in more than one country, which rarely happens.
So unfortunately however problematic it may seem you are obliged to pay your taxes where you sit (slight exceptions in case of delegations), no matter where your family is or where the company receiving services is located.

Comment: I think this is wrong.  If you live in Switzerland, but live in Germany (going home every night), you pay tax in *both* countries (but there is a dual taxation treaty so you end up just paying the German tax rates).

Comment: In addition, it is not at all clear to me that "studying at University" would establish tax residency.